# Prevent emacs mode from defining keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, evil, hooks

I am trying to extend evil-like conventions to comint mode so I can use vim-like key bindings from the shell. I also rebound `C-c` to `#'evil-normal-state` since that is what I use in vim (it isn't strictly equivalent to `C-[` but I haven't run into the weird edge cases where that actually matters yet).

I am using the `evil-define-key` macro to define `comint-mode`-specific bindings in normal state that begin with `SPC f` and so far that works great.

However, all the mode-specific key bindings beginning with `C-c` are still there despite the fact that `C-c` is bound to `#'evil-normal-state` in every state. I don't want to globally rebind `C-c` since that would interfere with emacs state.

What is the cleanest way to prevent `comint-mode` from defining any additional key bindings at all since evil-mode is effectively managing all the keys?

I have tried adding

```
(setf comint-mode-map (make-keymap))
```

and

```
(setf comint-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
```

to my `.emacs` file, but whenever I type `M-x shell`, I get the error

```
Wrong type argument: keymapp, 1
```

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: emacs uses the C-c prefix for a huge range of things, so you're going to be cutting yourself off from a lot of functionality (absent a lot of manual rebinding on your part) if you choose to take over C-c in this way.  Just about any other key (other than C-x or M-x) would probably be a less hassle-filled long-run choice.

Comment: If C-c is re-mapped only in the insert state it is no problem it will still keep original bindings in the normal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's really what you want to do, do it on `comint-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comint-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))))
```

You are probably getting that error because the comint code itself tries to bind keys on the prefix key `C-c`, but you have removed that.

Comment: I tried `emacs -Q -l patch-comint-mode-hook.el` with that just snippet. Inside the `M-x shell`-shell the `C-c` commands are still there.

Comment: Try doing the same for `shell-mode-hook`, as well.

Comment: patching the mode hooks for both comint mode and shell mode does not appear to suppress the keybindings. I used the following as my init file:  `(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comint-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))))
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (setq shell-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))))`